# Does Repository.walk traverse all commits

Tags: python, git, libgit2, pygit2

In `pygit2`, `Repository.walk` can be used to traverse commits starting from a commit.

However [the docs](http://www.pygit2.org/log.html) do not explictly say whether all commits in the repository will be traversed, including dangling commits, or just the parents and children of the starting commit.

If this does not include dangling commits, is there anything I can do to traverse them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found relevant material in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5249149/how-to-retrieve-all-object-ids).

`Repository.walk` does not care about dangling commits, however `git_odb_foreach` can be used, which in `pygit2` terms simply translates to iterating the repository object (check the `Repository_as_iter` function).